# Get Facebook IDs of users who liked a page's post after Feb 6th, 2018

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Until few days ago, it was possible to get the set of users who liked a page's post simply by:

```
/post_id/likes/
```

According to this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2017/11/07/marketing-api-v211/), it is not possible anymore, unless you have a page access token, which, in practice, means: unless you are the administrator of the page.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: use a page token. user data of pages you don´t manage are none of your business anyway.

Comment: "are none of your business anyway" = very fruitful comment.

Comment: well, that´s why the limitation was implemented. would be weird if there would be a workaround. there are also a lot of threads about this on stackoverflow already, btw.

Comment: thanks @luschn, can you point me out a stackoverflow thread about this topic?

Comment: Here is one just earlier today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680809/facebook-graph-api-return-en-empty-array-data